# git diff / format-patch output contains ^M (carriage return) character (Linux)

Tags: git, carriage-return

When I searched, I didn't see this problem for the unix side of things, just for Unix/MS incompatibility.

In my case, after editing existing source code (in emacs) and staging commits, the output generated by either `git diff` or `git format-patch` puts the carriage return character (^M) at the end of each line that I have added.

For instance, I run `git diff master --cached > patch.patch`. Looking at the file using emacs or vim shows `^M` at the end of every line of code. On the other hand, the character is not visible in nano, less, or cat. If I run `git diff master --cached`, in the less program that is started, `^M` characters are visible after every line of code I've added, but not in the source.

How do I solve this issue? I am using CentOS 6, emacs 24.5.1, and git 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

> core.autocrlf
>
> If you’re programming on Windows and working with people who are not (or vice-versa), you’ll probably run into line-ending issues at some point. This is because Windows uses both a carriage-return character and a linefeed character for newlines in its files, whereas Mac and Linux systems use only the linefeed character. This is a subtle but incredibly annoying fact of cross-platform work; many editors on Windows silently replace existing LF-style line endings with CRLF, or insert both line-ending characters when the user hits the enter key.
>
> Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code onto your filesystem. You can turn on this functionality with the core.autocrlf setting. If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true – this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code:
>
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf true
>
> If you’re on a Linux or Mac system that uses LF line endings, then you don’t want Git to automatically convert them when you check out files; however, if a file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced, then you may want Git to fix it. You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to input:
>
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf input
>
> This setup should leave you with CRLF endings in Windows checkouts, but LF endings on Mac and Linux systems and in the repository.
>
> If you’re a Windows programmer doing a Windows-only project, then you can turn off this functionality, recording the carriage returns in the repository by setting the config value to false:
>
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf false

This is from [Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: I don't know what operating system the source was written on, but I am not using windows, yet it seems that ^M characters are being added into the output of `git diff`. I have tried both core.autocrlf as input and false to no avail